# Put files on deployed PC's HDD during SCCM2012 OSD

Tags: wifi, imaging, sccm-2012

We are deploying Windows 7 using an OSD in SCCM 2012 SP1. We are doing this wirelessly. One of the things we are struggling on is automatically connecting to the Wireless.
A solution is to use NETSH WLAN Connect during the OSD but to do this we need to have the .xml file containing the profile, is it possible to pass this file over during OSD? We need to prestage all our content onto the local machine before boot as there is no network connectivity to anything until the wireless comes back up.

If there is a better way to initiate the connection then that would be great.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why are you trying to deploy computers over WiFi?

Comment: Some will be tablets, others will be laptops that we don't want to plug in if we don't need to. Also just to see if we can and what we can do with it.

Comment: For the love of god and all that is holy, simultaionusly deoplying a multi-gigabyte file over even a good wireless network is asking for performance and throughput issues. If the tablets don't have ethernet ports, I'd highly suggest a <whatever> to ethernet connector to make this easier and quicker for you.

Comment: It's an evaluation, just an evaluation. I appreciate the advice but we have to look at these things. I aggree that ethernet imaging is miles easier, it is also faster, without doubt, but we need to show evidence of this and alternatives.

Comment: @JoeTaylor With all due respect, you can conduct a reasonable feasibilty study on this with nothing other than a written comparison of 802.11n and Gigabit Ethernet. In short, imaging over wireless is overly complicated, slow, inconsistent, prone to failure and far more hassle than it'll ever be worth.

Comment: I get that but non technical people are not going to sit and read through all that. Put two machines side by side and show them, an exact task sequence running over ethernet and over wireless and no-one can't understand that.